# ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime' in OpenVINO

Tags: python, machine-learning, intel, openvino

I am trying to run the openvino notebook for object detection task as follows

```
from openvino import runtime as ov
```

But I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5dff2ebd5508> in <module>
      8 import numpy as np
      9 from IPython import display
---> 10 from openvino import runtime as ov
     11 from openvino.tools.mo.front import tf as ov_tf_front
     12 

ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime'
```

Comment: What version of OpenVINO do you have installed? `openvino.runtime` is a part of the [new API](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_2_0_inference_pipeline.html) introduced in the 2022.1 release. You probably have an older version installed.

Comment: I am using the version of v2022.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The "openvino.runtime" module is used to create a Core Object in the new OpenVINO API 2.0 Inference Engine Pipeline. The new API 2.0 was introduced starting in 2022.1.

Use  "from openvino.runtime import Core" to import OpenVINO.

Answer (score 0):

try this version, it worked for me

pip install 'openvino==2022.3.1'